# Re-render HTML when store updates - NGXS

Tags: angular, ngxs

I am using ngxs.. The store state is getting updated and i am getting values as required, but i also want to re-render HTML again when store value updated.

Right now my code says

```
this.store$ = this.store.select(state => state.departments.departments);
```

as soon as the departments are getting updated, i need my component to re-render HTML. I did it like

```
<ng-container *ngIf="state$ | async">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</ng-container>
```

Values are getting reflected but HTML not re rendering. 
I also tried

```
cdr.detectChanges(); or cdr.markForCheck()
```

but with no luck
Or my need will not be accomplished by store?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
this.store$.subscribe(cdr.markForCheck);
```

This will ensure that whenever the store$ observable changes, Angular will run its change detection on your component and update the view accordingly.

Another way to do this, is to denote store$ as an @Input() property. Because Angular continuously monitors all input properties to components, even when the changeDetectionStrategy is set to 'onPush'.

Comment: template does not reload at all with this as well

Comment: @SangamBelose, copy that. I've updated my answer with an explanation.

Comment: @Gags, no you shouldn't remove the async pipe, it's a separate subscription.

Comment: The async pipe handles the rerendering. I think the problem has nothing to do with rendering at all. I haven't tried it, but maybe the router-outlet is the problem? Not sure if you can/should dynamically add/remove that.